# destroying a weldjoint when a sprite reaches a specific position

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics, box2d-iphone

I have created a weldJoint between two sprites in my code (see update method below) and I also created a method that returns the exact position of a sprite when a mouseJoint is released. I want to compare the current position of the sprite to the spritePositionRelease value and destroy the weldJoint if the y values are the same and x values are different. Please help.

spritePositionRelease:

```
- (CGPoint)spritePositionRelease    {

for(b2Body *b = mouseJoint->GetBodyB(); b; b=b->GetNext())    {
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL)
    {
        CCSprite *mySprite = (CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();
        if (mySprite.tag == 1) {
            mySprite.position = CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
            CGPoint spritePosition = mySprite.position;
            CCLOG(@"the sprite position is x:%0.2f , y:%0.2f", spritePosition.x, spritePosition.y);

            return spritePosition;

        }
    }
}
}
```

ccTouchesEnded:

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

if (mouseJoint)
{
    [self spritePositionRelease];

    world->DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
    mouseJoint = NULL;
}
}
```

update:

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{
//It is recommended that a fixed time step is used with Box2D for stability
//of the simulation, however, we are using a variable time step here.
//You need to make an informed choice, the following URL is useful
//http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

int32 velocityIterations = 8;
int32 positionIterations = 1;

// Instruct the world to perform a single step of simulation. It is
// generally best to keep the time step and iterations fixed.
world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

// using the iterator pos over the set
std::set<BodyPair *>::iterator pos;

for(pos = bodiesForJoints.begin(); pos != bodiesForJoints.end(); ++pos)
{
    b2WeldJoint         *weldJoint;
    b2WeldJointDef      weldJointDef;

    BodyPair            *bodyPair = *pos;
    b2Body              *bodyA = bodyPair->bodyA;
    b2Body              *bodyB = bodyPair->bodyB;

    weldJointDef.Initialize(bodyA,
                            bodyB,
                            bodyA->GetWorldCenter());

    weldJointDef.collideConnected = false;
    weldJoint = (b2WeldJoint*) world->CreateJoint(&weldJointDef);

    // Free the structure we allocated earlier.
    free(bodyPair);

    // Remove the entry from the set.
    bodiesForJoints.erase(pos);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that mouseJoint->GetBodyB() will always return the right body? Maybe you should check mouseJoint->GetBodyA() to?

Anyway your check would be quite simple:

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

if (mouseJoint)
{
   CGPoint releasePoint = [self spritePositionRelease];
   CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[[touches anyObject] view]];
   if((releasePoint.y==touchPoint.y) &&(releasePoint.x!=touchPoint.x))
   {
//Destroy weld joint
   }
    world->DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
    mouseJoint = NULL;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate your help, I've been at it for a while. Maybe I didn't explain it well enough. When I release the sprite (using the spritePositionRelease) it will keep moving on it's own, so I want it's changing positions to be continually tracked and compared with the spritePositionRelease value. Not another touched point. Also, with my weldjoint created in the update method, how will I destroy it in the CCTouchesEnded method? When I use GetBodyA() the CCLOG in spritePositionRelease doesn't display the output.